# Read web.xml file from an ejb bean

Tags: jsf, glassfish, ejb

I want to know the authentication type if it is `ldap realm` or `jdbc realm`

I am not getting any solution in this problem
So i proposed to read the `web.xml` file from the jsf project
What i want is to read this file in the `ejb` project by an ejb bean

Is there any other solution other than my proposal

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the realm you can get an instance of it and check the type with `instanceof` like this:

```
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm;

//...

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance("realmName");

    if (realm instanceof JDBCRealm) {
      // do something
    }
```

If you don't have the name you may try your solution but I can't say if it will work because I think it will be difficult to get access to the `ServletContext` inside an EJB.